# How would I put a picture into the left cell?

Tags: html, css, layout

CSS code:

```
#wrapper {margin:auto; width:100%;}
.container {display: table; width:100%;}
.row {display: table-row;}
.cell {display: table-cell; height: 100px;} 
#fixed {width:150px;}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell" id="fixed">left cell</div>
<div class="cell">right cell</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How would I put a picture into the left cell? Suppose the picture to be 150px wide and 100px height.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by css,

```
.row { display:table:row ; background:url('images/myImage.png') no-repeat 0px 0px; }
```

In html

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cell" id="fixed"><img src="path/to/image.ext" alt="my picture" style="width:100px; height:100px"></div>
```

[HTML Images](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_images.asp)